# I broke my WiFi Card, Can I use my data antenna to connect to WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 2.3-gingerbread

I have an old android phone that I want to use to stream music while I am working around the house. Is it possible to make my data antenna work as a WiFi card? I am currently not rooted.

Here are the specs:

OS:Android (2.3.6, 2.3, 2.2)

Hardware

System chip:Qualcomm MSM7627-2

Processor:Single core, 600 MHz

System memory:512 MB RAM / 512 MB ROM

Storage expansion:microSD, microSDHC up to 32 GB

Technology

CDMA:800, 1900 MHz

Data:EV-DO Rev.A

Positioning:GPS

Navigation:Yes

Connectivity

Bluetooth:3.0

Wi-Fi:Yes

USB:Yes

Connector:microUSB

*Edit 
I should also mention that the damage was caused by water

Comment: How do you know you broke your WiFi card?

Comment: @mattm Water damage. I forgot it in my pocket, and it went through the wash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use your data antenna as a WiFi card. These are tuned to different frequencies, and the required processing for each is also different.